# Regex for obtaining numeric values within a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following example strings:

```
TAR:100
TAR:100|LED:50
TAR:30|LED:30|ASO:40
```

I need a regex that obtains the numeric values after the colon, which are always in the range 0 to 100 inclusive.

The result after the regex is applied to any of the above strings should be:

for `TAR:100` the result should be `100`

for `TAR:100|LED:50` the result should be the array `[100,50]`

for `TAR:30|LED:30|ASO:40` the result should be the array `[30,30,40]`

The word before the colon can have any length and both upper and lowercase.

I have tried with the following but it doesn't yield the result I need:

```
 String text = "TAR:100|LED:50";
 String pattern = "\\|?([a-zA-Z]{1,}:)";
 string[] values= Regex.Split(text, pattern);
```

The regex should work whether the string is `TAR:100` or `TAR:100|LED:50` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You added `()` which makes the text parts that you want to remove also be returned.

Below is my solution, with a slightly changed regex.

Note that we need to start looping the values at `i = 1`, which is *purely caused by using Split on a string that **starts** with a split-sequence*; it has nothing to do with the Regex itself.
Explanation: if we used a simpler [str.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) to split by a separator "#", then "a#b#c" would produce ["a", "b", "c"], whereas "#b#c" would produce ["", "b", "c"]. In general, and by definition: if Split removes N sequences by which the string gets splitted, then the result is N+1 strings. And all the strings that we deal with here are of the form "#b#c", so there is always an empty first result.

Accepting that as a given fact, the results are usable by starting from `i = 1`:

```
var pattern = @"\|?[a-zA-Z]+:";
var testCases = new[] { "TAR:100", "TAR:100|LED:50", "TAR:30|LED:30|ASO:40" };
foreach (var text in testCases)
{
    string[] values = Regex.Split(text, pattern);
    for (var i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
    Console.WriteLine("------------");
}
```

Output:

```
100
------------
100
50
------------
30
30
40
------------
```

Working DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/i9kH8n

Comment: thank you. any idea why the first element of the result array is a whitespace?

Comment: I gave it some more thought, and found an explanation for the (unavoidable) empty result. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET you can use the [Group.Captures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=net-5.0) and use the same name for 2 capture groups and match the format of the string.

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+:(?<numbers>[0-9]+)(?:\|[a-zA-Z]+:(?<numbers>[0-9]+))*\b
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%3a%28%3f%3cnumbers%3e%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5c%7c%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%3a%28%3f%3cnumbers%3e%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%29*%5cb&i=TAR%3a100%0d%0aTAR%3a100%7cLED%3a50%0d%0aTAR%3a30%7cLED%3a30%7cASO%3a40) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/VH93LS)

[image]

```
string[] strings = {
    "TAR:100",
    "TAR:100|LED:50",
    "TAR:30|LED:30|ASO:40"
    };
string pattern = @"\b[a-zA-Z]+:(?<numbers>[0-9]+)(?:\|[a-zA-Z]+:(?<numbers>[0-9]+))*\b";
foreach (String str in strings)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        string[] result = match.Groups["numbers"].Captures.Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(',', result));
    }
}
```

Output

```
100
100,50
30,30,40
```

Another option could be making use of the `\G` anchor and have the value in capture group 1.

```
\b(?:[a-zA-Z]+:|\G(?!^))([0-9]+)(?:\||$)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3a%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%3a%7c%5cG%28%3f!%5e%29%29%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5c%7c%7c%5cr%3f%24%29&i=TAR%3a100%0d%0aTAR%3a100%7cLED%3a50%0d%0aTAR%3a30%7cLED%3a30%7cASO%3a40&o=m) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/MNoTTS)

[image]

```
string[] strings = {
    "TAR:100",
    "TAR:100|LED:50",
    "TAR:30|LED:30|ASO:40"
    };
string pattern = @"\b(?:[a-zA-Z]+:|\G(?!^))([0-9]+)(?:\||$)";
foreach (String str in strings)
{
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, pattern);
    string[] result = matches.Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(',', result));
}
```

Output

```
100
100,50
30,30,40
```